# Constructing a map on anonymous function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am just learning the language and I've got a simple question. Why does this work (constructs `{:key "value"}`):

```
(#(assoc {} :key %) "value")
```

But this doesn't:

```
(#({:key %}) "value")
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

On Python the latter syntax is perfectly valid:

```
> (lambda v: {'key': v})('value')
{'key': 'value'}
```

edit: thanks for great answers, it is apparent I need to stop thinking `#` as equivalent to `lambda` in Python.

Comment: `#(f x) == (fn [] (f x)) :. #({x}) == (fn [] ({x}))`

Comment: It's a littly hacky but if you want to return an element from an anon fn: `#(-> {:key %})`

Comment: also `#(hash-map :k %)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#(f %)` is expanded by the reader into `(fn [%] (f %)`.  Likewise, `#({:key %})` is expanded into `(fn [%] ({:key %})`.  The python equivalent of this would be `lambda v: {'key': v}()`, which has the exact same problem as the Clojure version.

What you are looking for is something equivalent to `(fn [v] {:key v})`.  If you really want to use `#(...)` notation, you could use `#(do {:key %})`.

Incidentally, I personally never use `#(...)`.  I think it's more difficult to grok (as examples such as this evidence), and is only very slightly more compact than an equivalent `fn` form.  Then there's also the limitation that `#(...)` forms can not be nested.

Answer (score 5):

That is the limitation of `#()` reader. `fn` will work fine.

```
user=> ((fn [x] {:key x}) "value")
{:key "value"}
```

Please take a look at the document [Anonymous function literal (#())](http://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch)

Comment: What limitation are you referring to?  The only limitation I see from the link you posted is that "#() forms cannot be nested."  But that doesn't apply in this situation....

Comment: According to the document, `#(…​)` will be translated to `(fn [args] (…​))`. So `#({:key %})` will be translated to `(fn [x] ({:key x}))`. This will cause error because `{:key x}` is in function position and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`{:key %}` is a PersistentArrayMap.  You have it in the "verb position" in your function call.  You need a Clojure method of some type in there to avoid that error, as you can see in your first (working) example.