# Clojure: clojure.lang.ArityException when returning map from reader macro function

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I can return a map from function with following syntax

```
(defn retmap [bar] { :foo bar })
```

How do I achieve the same with reader macro syntax? I tried following

```
(def retmap #({:foo %}))
```

But calling this function `(retmap)` gives the error

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructing a map on anonymous function in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734468/constructing-a-map-on-anonymous-function-in-clojure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hash-map`:

```
(def retmap #(hash-map :foo %))
```

You can see why your example throws an exception by expanding the macro:

```
(macroexpand `#({:foo %}))
=> (fn* [x] ({:foo x}))
```

so the constructed map is immediately invoked as a function with no arguments. Maps are functions from keys to values so require an argument to be provided.

Comment: You could explain why the literal doesn't work to gain the check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

Another answer which is sometimes quite handy is to use `identity`:

```
(def retmap #(identity {:foo %}))
```

The `identity` function is used when you are forced to use a function, but you don't want it to do anything

```
(identity {:foo 42})  => {:foo 42}

(def retmap #(identity {:foo %}))
(retmap 42)  ;=>  {:foo 42}
```